# Date display in template for Google structured data

Tags: django

I'm working on SEO for my blog and I'm building structured data for Google.
I think I have to get this date format : 2018-12-13T10:50:00+00:00

Currently, my date is like this because I don't know how to do better :

```
    <script type="application/ld+json">{
        "@context":"http:\/\/schema.org",
        "@type":"NewsArticle",
        "dateCreated":"{{post.date|date:"Y-m-d H:i:s"}}",
```

Anyone knows how to transform post.date to return something like 2018-12-13T10:50:00+00:00 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for the [**ISO 8601 format**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). This format is specified with the [**`c` formatter**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date):

> **Format character**: `c`
>
> **Description**: ISO 8601 format. (Note: unlike others formatters, such as `"Z"`, `"O"` or
>   `"r"`, the `"c"` formatter will not add timezone offset if value is a
>   naive datetime (see `datetime.tzinfo`).
>
> **Example output**: `2008-01-02T10:30:00.000123+02:00`, or `2008-01-02T10:30:00.000123` if the
>   datetime is naive

So for example if we use `utcnow()`, we get:

```
>>> Template('{{x|date:"c"}}').render(Context({'x': datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc)}))
'2018-12-16T13:48:46.047534+00:00'
```